# Which part costs the most in terms of performance in this C-code?

Tags: c, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I have to answer a question about a relatively simple C-code snippet. In the function below, what would be the most costly in terms of performance or time complexity? I really have no idea how to answer that because I feel it depends on the if-statement. Also I don't know if a comparison is costly or not, same goes for a return, a struct access and multiplication.

Btw, the *info_h* is a struct.

```
RGBPixel* bm_get_pixel_at(
    unsigned int x,
    unsigned int y,
    RGBPixel *pixel_array )
{
    int index;
    int width_with_padding = info_h.width;
    if( x >= info_h.width || y >= info_h.height ){ return &blackPixel; }
    index = (info_h.height-1 - y) * width_with_padding + x;
    return pixel_array + index;
}
```

***EDIT:***

Okay so the question might have been a bit oddly phrased. I should add that this is just one function out of many in a bit more complex c program which we have now ran a oprofile script thirty times on. The script then returns the results of average times each procedure was sampled by oprofile. In that results table, this function came in at third most sampled. The follow up question is therefore, which part of this function causes the program to spend third most of its time inside it? Sorry if it was a bit unclear in the beginning

Comment: Time complexity is O(1), there is no loop or recursion. This function is probably inlined anyway.

Comment: There is no big deal in the code, if you think your program is slow, you have to profile its performance so you can find the bottleneck.

Comment: "what" as in "which part of this"? In that case please identify the parts in question.

Comment: The largest part of the cost is probably the function-calling overhead.(if not inlined)

Comment: What do you mean by "costly"? The absolute time spent doing it? The most inefficient, i.e. the part which could be optimised most? Those two are different questions.

Comment: Okay so the question might be oddly phrased but it might be because I have translated it from swedish. I will update the post with more detailed information

Comment: Okay now it is updated with clearer information

Comment: To me it looks like the function is called a lot. Doesn't mean the function itself has any perf issues.

Comment: I am not saying there should be any performance issues. I just wanna know kind of what row would take the longest... I dunno even why the teacher has decided to ask this. I too feel it is a weird question...

Comment: It all looks fine. The most expensive part will probably be the `info_h.width` and `&blackPixel` parts, which require access to `static` / global variables (I'm assuming) and will (probably / maybe) invalidate the CPU cache. The math operations a cheap (even though `+` is faster than `-`, etc').

Comment: Sorry guys. My mindset was all wrong when trying to tackle this question. I have marked an answer as accepted because it made me realize that I had understood the question wrong. The answer should be because of the amount of times it is called. Not because of anything inside the function. THanks to everyone who responded nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've omitted the rest of your program, it all turns into guesswork. That this function shows up a lot in your profiling result is likely due to it being called inside an inner loop. What this function does (it's pretty obvious) is, that it returns the memory location of a pixel or, if the requested index lies outside of the bounds of the pixel array, returns the memory location of a dummy pixel.

If you run that function inside a loop, then the bounds check is executed for each and every iteration, which of course is quite redundant. This is a really low-hanging fruit regarding optimization: Put the bounds checks before the loop, and make sure, that the loop itself doesn't venture outside the bounds:

```
static inline
RGBPixel* bm_get_pixel_at_UNSAFE(
    unsigned int x,
    unsigned int y,
    RGBPixel *pixel_array )
{
    size_t const width_with_padding = info_h.width;
    size_t const index = ((size_t)info_h.height-1 - y) * width_with_padding + x;
    return &pixel_array[index];
}

RGBPixel* bm_get_pixel_at(
    unsigned int x,
    unsigned int y,
    RGBPixel *pixel_array )
{
    return ( x < info_h.width && y < info_h.height ) ?
          bm_get_pixel_at_UNSAFE(x,y, pixel_array)
        : &blackPixel;
}

void foo(RGBPixel *pixel_array)
{
    /* iteration stays inside array bounds */
    for( unsigned int y = 0; y < info_h.height; ++y )
    for( unsigned int x = 0; x < info_h.width;  ++x ){
        RGBPixel *px = bm_get_pixel_at_UNSAFE(x, y, pixel_array);
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are probably right about why it shows up a lot. This is also what I thought but now as I am typing this reply I just realized the answer. The question was a bit oddly phrased so I got confused and thought I was supposed to identify something in the code but I think the answer is "because it is being called so many times". That is why it shows up a lot, as you said. I had my mindset all wrong. Thanks again